# Outputs from referencing two tables

Tags: sql, join

```
EID NAME           SALARY DNAME                      HIRE_DATE NUM_PHONES
--- ------------------ ---------- ---------------------- --------- ----------
111 Yo-yo Ma            80000 Software               01-MAY-81      1
222 Leonard Bernstein   80000 Information Technology 02-JUN-82      2
333 Leonard Bernstein   110000 Research              03-JUL-83      1
444 Yehudi Menuhin      60000 Software               02-JAN-91      3
555 Lata Mangeshkar     50000 Software               01-MAY-81      5
666 Bing Crosby         65000 Tech Support           02-JUN-82      2
777 Frank Sinatra       40000 Tech Support           04-APR-84

DNAME                      BUDGET    EXPENSE REGION
---------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Software                   800000     600000 Eastern
Tech Support              2000000    3000000 Eastern
Information Technology    3000000    3000000 Western
Research                   100000      60000 Western

EID PHONENUM
--- ----------
111 2372918458
222 5051734849
222 5755851934
333 1513664917
444 2206315710
444 3321045029
444 5678540401
444 5752658931
555 2546768967
555 5756390131
555 7201014829

EID PHONENUM
--- ----------
555 7595120111
555 7597209076
666 1513664917
666 5053241942
777 5753241942
```

Find the ID and name of employees with at least one phone in 575 area code but none in the 505 area code.

I've tried the below action and can't get around the dual eid attributes.  Please help!

```
SQL> select eid, phonenum, name
  2  from phone, emp
  3  where emp.eid = phone.eid and
  4  phonenum like '575%'
  5  and not like '505%'
  6  ;
select eid, phonenum, name
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone numbers starting with 575 or 505 are in different rows, so it's not as simple as applying two LIKE conditions **to the same row**. Solution is creating subqueries and check if what we're looking for exists using a condition and does not using the other.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eid, e.name
FROM emp e
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM phone p1 WHERE p1.eid = e.eid AND p1.phonenum LIKE '575%')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM phone p2 WHERE p2.eid = e.eid AND p2.phonenum LIKE '505%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select eid, phonenum, name
  2  from phone, emp
  3  where emp.eid = phone.eid and
```

Even though the query specifies `emp.eid = phone.eid`, the reference to `eid` on the first line is ambiguous.  (I think that's what the asterisk underneath it later on is indicating.)

SQL requires that each reference to a column name that occurs in more than one table be explicitly named, equality not withstanding.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is use LEFT JOIN's and existence conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eid, e.name
FROM emp 
   LEFT JOIN phone AS Area575 ON (Area575.eid = emp.eid) AND (Area575.phonenum LIKE '575%')
   LEFT JOIN phone AS Area505 ON (Area575.eid = emp.eid) AND (Area575.phonenum LIKE '505%')
WHERE
   Area575.eid IS NOT NULL AND
   Area505.eid IS NULL
```